# Global node settings

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun, nodemailer

Forgive me if I have used the wrong terminology to describe my issue, please do correct me. I am developing in node and express. I want to be able to call nodemailer from anywhere in my app without re-creating the transporter. How do I do this, I had thought that I just needed to put this in app.js and then it would work. I am using mailgun-nodemailer.

app.js

```
var auth = {
auth: {
   api_key: 'key-XXXXX',
   domain: 'XXXXX.mailgun.org'
 }
}

var mailgun = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));
```

acontroller.js

```
mailgun.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! Your password has been changed.' });
    done(err);
  });
```

Comment: You can assign the `mailgun` client to the `app` Express object and then use it from any route...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the keyword `var` and use `global` instead so you `mailgun` is global.
You'll need to load the file using `require('app.js')` at the start of your application too. (before you need to call it, so basically when you start express I'd say)

```
var auth = {
auth: {
   api_key: 'key-XXXXX',
   domain: 'XXXXX.mailgun.org'
 }
}

global.mailgun = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));
```

Note that you also may use `module.exports.mailgun = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth))` and then load it using

```
require('app.js').mailgun.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! Your password has been changed.' });
    done(err);
  });
```

In that case I would advise you to rename the file `app.js` to `mailgun.js`, makes more sense.

So there are two way, either a global var or using the usual node.js require function, do as you want, we usually use the `require` way, but if you don't want to be worried about paths then using a global var makes sense.

Comment: Defining variables without `var` should not be encouraged - strict mode forbids (for good reason) such operation. If you really want to declare a globally available variable, assign it to the `global` object directly.